# SMS messaging when tethered to phone in Yosemite, not just iMessages

Tags: ios, macos, messages, sms

Ive got facetime on my laptop working with my phone which allows me to make and receive calls (these are phone calls as opposed to facetime audio calls).

Ive also got messages on my laptop but with the messages it seems to only let me send and receive imessages is there a way i can set it up to also allow me to make and receive incoming SMS messages ?

On the [apple support website](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20148?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) i can see that that it seems to be possible, but when i got to messages on my machine i only get the option to iMessage.

---

My laptop is an MBP running 10.10.5, My phone is a iphone5s running iOS8.x (latest 8 version)

This is my current messages setup :
[image]

And this is the setup on my phone :

[image]

Comment: please try troubleshooting with this guide: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204678

Comment: Thanks, I've had a run through of that and it all seems to be configured correctly, oddly Facetime calls from my computer using my mobile phone work so it seems to be partially working just not for SMS

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-send-sms-texts-in-yosemite-3582821/

Follow the link above it worked for me. All the best.

Make sure you are signed in to iCloud on both your iOS device and Mac using the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need Messages set up to receive at your phone number as well as email addresses, like this

[image]

& start new conversations from the phone number too.

Comment: Thanks thats how i have it setup, please see edited question which ive added a screenshot of my setup to